# Using Generic/Parameterized java with multiple classes

Tags: java, generics

I am attempting to create a generic/parameterized code to call from multiple classes I have. I will code it so I have several classes that have methods of the same name, so I'm hoping to create a generic way to call them.

Say I have 3 different classes that will all have methods that are called getAmount() that return ints and toString() methods that return Strings

Then I want a generic class that could possibly reference any of those three.

```
    public class Stuff<Project> {

    private Project p;

    public Stuff(Project aProject) {
       this.p = aProject;
    }

    public int getValue() {
       return p.getAmount();
    }

    public String toString() {
       return p.toString();
    }
```

Is there anything in java that would get this functionality for me, or am i thinking in C?
I've tried using Object.getClass() in various ways to attempt to cast things, and several of the other Generic programming related questions on this site and the docs.oracle site don't seem to have what I'm looking for. Is this not possible because of the way type erasure works?

Comment: Every class has a `toString` method, but don't need to do anything - just create a method that takes `Object` and calls `toString`. As far as `getAmount` goes, this comes down to polymorphism. You need to `interface` that declares a `getAmount` method and your classes can then `implements` it. There are no templates in Java.

Comment: java generics is concept in java api.its upto you how you would make use of it. and yes for your case you will have to do your own impl you will not get it out of the box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use generics here, use interfaces. In Java, you use interfaces to tell the compiler that a class implements certain methods, without telling it how these methods are implemented.

```
public interface Project {
    int getAmount();
}
public class Stuff {
    private Project p;
    public Stuff(Project aProject) {
        this.p = aProject;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return p.getAmount();
    }
}
```

You can pass an instance of any class to `Stuff`'s constructor, as long as it implements the `Project` interface:

```
public class Construction implements Project {
    public int getAmount() {
        // implementation
    }
}
...
Stuff s = new Stuff(new Construction());
```

Comment: thanks! a quick google of java interface to find the doc (and then back to your answer to understand it) did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interface, an abstract class or reflection. I would avoid using reflection unless you really need it. This looks like the perfect job for an interface.

```
public interface Ammount {
    public int getAmmount();
}


public class BankAccount implements Ammount {

    @Override
    public int getAmmount() {
        return -10; // broke
    }
}

public class PiggyBank implements Ammount {

    @Override
    public int getAmmount() {
        return 12; // rich
    }
}
```

You can then use some code like

```
BankAccount myBankAccount = new BankAccount();
Ammount ammount = myBankAccount;
ammount.getAmmount();

PiggyBank myPiggyBank = new PiggyBank();
Ammount ammount = myPiggyBank;
ammount.getAmmount();
```